# Autocomplete doesn't suggest Integer but knows about parseInt

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, autocomplete, code-completion

Is it normal that my Android Studio doesn't show autocompletion for the `Integer` type?

When I type `Integer` here it doesn't appear in the autocomplete but after typing the `.` the autocomplete now knows there is `parseInt`. This is pretty uncool. Is there a way to fix that behaviour or have I just found a bug? How is that possible that it is not suggesting me this type and even when I write its complete name, it's not on the list. The closest type it shows is `IntegerRes`.

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

     // [-----] = nothing
     //        . = autocomplete works
        Integer.parseInt // <-- HERE

        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->

            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow your question? Are you aware that you spelled `Integer`, as `Ingeter`?

Comment: @PiRocks oh! That's a type in the editor here... let me fix it.

Comment: To clarify, the issue is that you aren't getting completion for Integer, the class, while getInteger, the method is fine?

Comment: @PiRocks well, basically when I want to use this type and probably others, I have to type it completely as if I was writing an ordinary string. Autocomplete is not helping.

Comment: @PiRocks exactly! I wonder how can it know about what methods Integer has but the type itself is apparently unknown.

Comment: So it may be intentional to discourage the use of the Integer class which is more java specific.

Comment: If you want to use convert string to int in kotlin I believe the official/correct way is `.toInt()`

Comment: @PiRocks oh, this actually makes a lot of sense! :-o